# show the whole text when clicking read more vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

i have a description section that shows only the first 100 word and when clicking read more it shows the whole description.

it works fine! my problem is when clicking read more it shows the complete description of all posts

code:

```
    <template>
  <div class="page container">
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="post">
        <p class="p h5">{{post.title}}</p>
        <p class="p" v-if="!readActivated">{{post.description.slice(0,100)}}<span class="read" v- 
        if="!readActivated" @click="activateReadMore">..read more</span></p>
        <p class="p" v-if="readActivated">{{post.description}}</p>
        <img class="img img-fluid" :src="'storage/'+post.path" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return{
            readActivated: false
        }
    },
    methods:{
        activateReadMore(){
            this.readActivated = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a `readActivated` for each post.
your data structure should be like

```js
data() {
  return {
    posts: [
      {title: 'some text...', ..., readMore: false},
      {title: 'some text...', ..., readMore: false},
      {title: 'some text...', ..., readMore: false},
    ]
  }
}
```

inside your HTML it should looke like this:

```html
<div class="page container">
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="post">
        <p class="p h5">{{post.title}}</p>
        <p class="p" v-if="!readActivated">{{post.description.slice(0,100)}}<span class="read" 
           v-if="!readActivated" @click="post.readMore = !post.readMore">..read more</span></p> // <----- toggle each single readMore related to its item
        <p class="p" v-if="post.readMore">{{post.description}}</p> //<-- show only thoose which have "readMore" set to true 
        <img class="img img-fluid" :src="'storage/'+post.path" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

at the moment all your posts will be controlled by one single `readActivated` but each post need there own `readActivated` to work as you wish

---

#### quick update

when fetching your posts from your backend you can loop them and add a `readActivated` for each like so.

```js
// fetch stuff... here 
.then(res => {
  const posts = res.data
  for (const post of posts) {
    post.readActivated = false
  }
})
```

now each post got his very own `readActivated`

Comment: thanks deniz, makes sense, now i should go back and add the property to my database

Comment: you can add these props in frontend too.
no need to add a prop for that in your database